# Is it possible to move transmission (with all running torrents and downloaded data) from ubuntu GUI onto a transmission-remote server?

Tags: ubuntu, remote, transmission

I currently have transmission running on a PC running Ubuntu desktop which I leave running continuously.

It currently has over a hundred torrents in various levels of activity uploading and downloading.

I want to move these onto an Ubuntu Server system running transmission-remote on a more energy efficient former thin wire client machine.

I am hoping that transmission stores all the torrent data somewhere and that it is compatible between the GUI version on my Ubuntu desktop and the remote system I intend to set up on my Ubuntu Server system.

Can it be done and if so any advice/information very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Transmission-gtk is a graphical frontend to the transmission daemon, anyways. So, you're already doing what you plan to do, already: you can start and control that same daemon using a command line tool.

Yes, that daemon does store all its torrent information in a simple directory. I think you can even see the location of the torrent file (not only the data) in the torrent properties.

Beware, though, that torrenting is a relatively CPU-intense thing, and requires storage to be accessed in very non-linear ways, so it very heavily benefits in power efficiency from more RAM, at least on hard drives. So if your workstation has a modern CPU and an SSD, but your thin client an old CPU and a hard drive, it's not per se clear that the thin client is more power efficient! The powertop tool on Linux might give some insight in how much power consumption can be attributed to transmission-server. Measure before you try to optimize!